# Defining include path for mingw compiler

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to use Mingw compiler on Linux OS for cross-compiling to Windows binaries.

In the very simple project I use one include:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

The *json.hpp* is located in `/usr/include/nlohmann`.
When I compile the project via g++, the compiler looks for its default include paths and is able to find the header file without problems.

However, when I compile the project via mingw, it uses different include paths, so I have to specify the include path explicitly. I use this command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I/usr/include/nlohmann --static main.cpp
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal error: nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

Can anybody help me please?
NOTE: the *json.hpp* file depends on other files from *nlohmann* folder, so including only the json.hpp file will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW not searching `/usr/include` is actually a good thing. Libraries in there might not work with MinGW.

Now, nlohmann/json itself, being header-only and without any platform-specific generated headers, might work as is. But trying to add <s>`-I/usr/include`</s> to flags (which would let the compiler find the file) would cause huge problems, as all the other headers in there might get used as well.

Instead, what you should do is to clone [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) yourself, and add the `include/` directory in the repo to the search path (with `-I`).

---

Also there's [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which has a package manager for MinGW libraries. Though for header-only libraries that don't need to be compiled, the benefit of using it is rather small (not having to manually clone the repo and set the include path). (I'm the author.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Copying the headers to my project is probably the best solution. Speaking of libraries, I have a few static Linux-type libraries that I use in my project when working in Linux OS. Would those also work using MinGW? (Will the MinGQ linker accept them and successfully link them to valid Exe file) Or do I have to somehow recompile the static libraries via MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is located at `/usr/include/nlohmann/json.hpp` and the include line is

```c
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

what you need is `-I/usr/include`.

Then it will find `nlohmann/json.hpp` under `/usr/include`.

Note that it's only okay to do this if this is a header-only library that is not different for the specific target platform you are cross-compiling to.

In general you need to have dependency libraries compiled for the same target platform and link with them. That's also the reason the cross compiler won't look at the stuff in `/usr/include`.

Comment: Since you can't choose what gets pulled from `/usr/include`, including it is probably not the best idea.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yea, I agree